# Rails has_many, :through - updating join table column when creating associated objects

Tags: join, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

**My question**

How do I set the initial "job_position" (column in the checklists_jobs join table for this has_may, :through association) for a new Checklist's Jobs when the Checklist is created? My best guess is that I should be using a callback (after_filter in the Checklists Controller?).

I also need to apply this same method to the Update controller action, but I suspect the code will be nearly identical.

**Use case**

I'm creating Checklists and associated Jobs (tasks) in a single form. From this form, users can create a new Checklist (Name, Description), and create new Jobs (Name, Description) and/or select existing Jobs from a pick-list.

The actual form is in my "code" section below, but here's a summary of what a user would see when creating a new Checklist:

- Checklist name:
- Checklist description (optional):

("Add a new job" link) - if link is clicked, I use JS to append a new Job (blank) to the form:

- Job name:
- Job description (optional):

Add Jobs from the Job bank:

- (checkbox) Existing Job 1
- (checkbox) Existing Job 2

CREATE CHECKLIST (button)

On my join table (checklists_jobs), I have the requisite checklist_id and job_id fields, but I also have a "job_position" field, which tells me the display order of the Jobs on that Checklist. (I will mostly do this via the "unarchived_jobs" association shown in the Checklist.rb code below.)

**How it's working right now**

Right now, I'm not setting the "job_position" field during Checklist creation, so it's just null. Users can manually set "job_position" by sorting the checklist on the Checklists#Show page (after the checklist is created). But I want to set the job_position attribute for the join record when the checklist is created, to make sure I preserve/reflect the user's actual positioning *when they created the list* (eg, the order in which they added new jobs using the "add new jobs" link). **NOTE:** This is for Jobs they add using the "add new job" link. The Jobs chosen from the pick-list will obviously need to be sorted manually by the user after the Checklist is created.

How do I do this?

## Code

**checklist.rb**

```
class Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :archived_state, lambda {|s| where(:archived => s) }

  has_many :checklists_jobs, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'checklists_jobs.job_position'
  has_many :jobs, :through => :checklists_jobs
  has_many :unarchived_jobs, :through => :checklists_jobs, 
           :source => :job, 
           :conditions => ['checklists_jobs.archived = ?', false], :order => 'checklists_jobs.job_position'
end
```

**job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :archived_state, lambda {|s| where(:archived => s)}

  has_many :checklists_jobs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :checklists, :through => :checklists_jobs
end
```

**checklists_job.rb**

```
class ChecklistsJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :archived_state, lambda {|s| where(:archived => s) }

  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :checklist
  attr_accessible :job_position, :job_required
end
```

**_form.html.erb (new Checklist form)**

```
<%= form_for @checklist, :html => { :class => 'form-inline' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :name, :rows => 1, :placeholder => 'Name the list...', :class => 'autoresizer checklist-name' %></br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 1, :placeholder => 'Optional description...', :class => 'autoresizer' %>

    <%= f.fields_for :jobs, :html => { :class => 'form-inline' } do |j| %>
      <%= render "job_fields", :j => j  %>
    <% end %>

    <span class="add-new-job-link"><%= link_to_add_fields "add a new job", f, :jobs %></span>

    <% unless @job_list.empty? %>
    <legend>Add jobs from the Job Bank</legend>

    <% @job_list.each do |job| %>
      <div class="toggle">
        <label class="checkbox text-justify" for="<%=dom_id(job)%>">
          <%= check_box_tag "new_jobs[]", job.id, false, id: dom_id(job) %><strong><%= job.name %></strong> <small><%= job.description %></small>
        </label>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', checklists_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion from a friend, I solved this using the [acts_as list gem](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list). It was trivial to implement despite a few custom tweaks I needed. The default :column is 'position', so I had to override that. I also needed a custom scope as I'm using this for a has_many, :through join table, and I have 'archived' items in that table (that I don't want to order on updates, etc.).

Below is the line of code necessary to make these tweaks:

**checklists_job.rb**

```
acts_as_list :column => 'job_position', :scope => 'checklist_id = #{checklist_id} AND archived = false'
```

This is simply added to the code I initially included with my question.

[#147 Sortable Lists (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised) briefly mentions acts_as_list. The mention is brief mostly due to how easy it is to install and use.

Comment: How'd you fix this? I am still unclear with how you made this work for adding to a column in the join table

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy I used the acts_as_list gem, and specifically used it in the model (.rb file) for the join table. I added that "acts_as_list :column => 'job_position"... line so that the "job_position" column would keep track of position. The acts_as_list gem itself takes care of the "set initial position".

I think the trick was calling out the name of the column to use as the position since it wasn't the standard "position" that acts_as_list expects.